# my transaction triplicates and all of them fail

Tags: solidity, contract-development, javascript, ganache, truffle-migration

I am new to creating smart contracts, I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coQ5dg8wM2o) in order to create a simple to-do list. I needed to update some code in order to make it work since the video is more than 2 years old. This is my [code](https://github.com/robertvitoriano/blockchain-todo-list), all the tests are passing, wallet connects with ganache, I did the migrations with truffle but when I try to create a new to-do from the client side I get the message:"This transaction is expected to fail. Trying to execute it is expected to be expensive but fail, and is not recommended.". I execute it anyway and it fails giving me  [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL5cQ.png). I also noticed that the transaction [triplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUp8P.png).

this is my call to the createTask function on the client:

```
    createTask: async(e) =>{
     e.preventDefault();
  
     const newTaskInput = document.querySelector('#new-task-input');
     const newTaskContent = newTaskInput.value;
     await App.todoList.createTask('newTaskContent',{from:App.account, value:1e17})
     window.location.reload();
```

```
And this is the contract code:
```

```
uint public taskCount = 0;

struct Task {
  uint id;
  string content;
  bool completed;
}

mapping(uint => Task) public tasks;

event TaskCreated(
  uint id,
  string content,
  bool completed
);

  event TaskCompleted(
   uint id,
   bool completed
 );
constructor() {
  createTask("Check out this contract");
}

function createTask(string memory _content) public {
  taskCount++;
  tasks[taskCount] =  Task(taskCount, _content, false);
  emit TaskCreated(taskCount, _content, false);
}
```

I read some texts saying the problem is in the generated JSON in the build folder, wasn't able to find it out.

Comment: Create Task function is not a 'payable' function, try not passing 'value'.

Comment: When I don't pass the 'value' parameter I get 'Insufficient funds message' from metamask.

Comment: Do you have balance in your address?

Comment: Yes, 100.000 ETH from ganache account